# Rotation of axes help?

Tags: coordinate-systems

This is not a duplicate of my other question in regard to this.

I really am not understanding this rotation of axes stuff. If we want to graph a 45 degree shifted ellipse for example, we can think of it as in the XY plane as a normal ellipse but then when we convert the X's and Y's into equivalent forms in terms of x and y, the graph is graphed the way it was in the XY plane but now in the xy plane. It seems as if this would just give you the ellipse in the xy plane not shifted at all. Every X and Y is given a value in terms of x and y, so aren't these coordinates giving you the same exact thing?

Comment: Once you rotate axes, X,Y become your real x,y and the previous x,y do not exist. They are your world now

Comment: So is it correct to say that every (X,Y) has been converted into (x,y), such that the two coordinates in respective planes have the same point?

Comment: This is where I'm confused because if so, (x,y) and (X,Y) have the same point. Why are the conversions necessary?

Comment: The original XY-axis is rotated with respect to the new xy-axis.  Draw them both and you will see that your new viewpoint is looking at the xy-axis.  The XY-axis should be drawn rotated (or translated or both) from the xy-axis.  If you turn (or move) your head, you see the XY-axis and the xy-axis is rotated/translated away.  For each point in the XY-axis (the simple ellipse) you can project to your new coordinates, the xy-axis, by dropping perpendiculars to the rotated away xy-axis...a picture would help.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to understand a plane without any axes. Then arbitrarily introduce any one direction as x axes and then y-axes. You can then write its position in a better way. Now you want to know what would have happened if you took some other axes.

Comment: Conversions are necessary so as to make the equations look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture of rotating an ellipse's axis:

[image]

Note that although it looks like $x = Y$ and $y = X$, this is not the case.  Notice that the coordinates $(x, y)$ are the [rotated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) of $(X, Y)$ through $\phi$ (which is $30^\circ$ for my picture):

$$
x = X\cos\left(\phi\right) - Y\sin\left(\phi\right) \\
y = X\sin\left(\phi\right) + Y\cos\left(\phi\right)
$$

...which would be $x  = \frac{\sqrt{3}X - Y}{2}$ and $y = \frac{X + \sqrt{3}Y}{2}$ for my picture ($\phi = 30^\circ$).

Comment: My confusion is coming from this. (x,y) and (X,Y) get you to the same point in space, so I'm not understanding how if we are graphing the same points in space to get the ellipse rotated, then why isn't every X and Y just the x and y in the picture? They are not equal like you said but they get us to the same point? So what's up with these conversions?

Comment: @KingSquirrel The coordinates determine where things are.  The choice of coordinate system is an arbitrary choice thus two people may look at the same thing but choose different coordinate systems.  If they are indeed looking at the same thing then there should exist a transformation between the two systems such that person $1$ could see what person $2$ sees and vice versa.  This literally means that person one could transform its coordinates, read them off to person $2$, then person $2$ would agree that this is what person $2$ sees and likewise for person $2$ to person $1$.

Comment: In my example, the left picture is what XY sees and the right picture is what xy sees.  You can see this in two ways: $1$) as a transformation of what XY sees, to bring xy to the "front" (so that $x$ is horizontal and $y$ is vertical) or $2$) as a transformation of what $xy$ sees, to bring XY to the "front".  For the first, we need to rotate _counter-clockwise_ by $30^\circ$ and the second _clockwise_ by $30^\circ$.